# Relations between radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $R$ denote the radius of convergence. Then $\sum_{n=0} a_{2n} x^{2n}$ has $R = 2$, and $\sum_{n=0} a_{3n} x^{3n}$ has $R = 3$. How to prove that $\sum_{n=0} a_{n} x^{n}$ has $R \leq 2$?

For simplification suppose that $a_n > 0\quad \forall n$. Then the following could be written:$$\frac {a_{2n} }{a_{2n+2}} = 2; \frac {a_{3n} }{a_{3n+3}} = 3 \Rightarrow a_{2n+2} = \frac 12 a_{2n}; a_{3n+3} = \frac 13 a_{3n}$$All three series share common $a_0$, thus $a_{2} = \frac 12 a_{0}; a_{3} = \frac 13 a_{0}$.

Comment: It is incorrect to write $\;\frac{a_{2n}}{a_{2n+2}}=2\;$ etc., as this is not the way nor it follows from the formula to get the convergence radius.

Comment: You mean, I "forgot" limit?

Comment: In fact, you forgot lim. sup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you know that following result: If a power series $\sum a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $r$, then $\sum a_n x^n$ converges *absolutely* for any $x$ such that $|x|\lt r$.

Suppose now that $\sum_1^\infty a_n x^n$ has radius of convergence $r\gt 2$. Let $s$ be strictly between $2$ and $r$. Then
$$\sum |a_n|s^n$$ 
converges.

This cannot be the case, since $\sum |a_{2n}| s^{2n}$ diverges. (This follows from the given fact that this series has radius of convergence $2$.)

We conclude that $r\le 2$, which is what we needed to show.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for such simple proof.

Comment: The quick argument uses $\limsup$. The reason I wrote the above proof is that I wanted to use (with detail filled in) what radius of convergence *means*, not a *formula* for radius of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

We have the radius of convergence $1/R=\limsup_{n\ge 1}|b_n|^{1/n}$ for a power series $\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nz^n$.

Clearly, $ \limsup_{n\ge 1}|a_n|^{1/n}\ge \max (\limsup_{n\ge 1}|a_{2n}|^{1/2n},\limsup_{n\ge 1}|a_{3n}|^{1/3n})$, so we conclude that $R\le \min(2,3)=2$.